# rtl8723bs wireless problems after upgrade to jammy

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, realtek-wireless

Everything worked well on 20.04 Ubuntu but after I upgraded to jammy (22.04) wireless stil (somewhat) works but it keeps giving this d/c's clogging the logs and making some apps reload (since it thinks the ip/hostnames have changed).

Everything seems to be coming from rtl8723bs **mmc0:0001:1 wlan0: rtw_ndev_notifier_call(wlan0) state:4**

```
Sep 11 13:27:17 kernel: [ 2399.719924] rtl8723bs mmc0:0001:1 wlan0: rtw_ndev_notifier_call(wlan0) state:4
Sep 11 13:27:17 wpa_supplicant[1049]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=[router-mac] reason=0 locally_generated=1
Sep 11 13:27:17 wpa_supplicant[1049]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Sep 11 13:27:17 systemd-networkd[851]: wlan0: Lost carrier
Sep 11 13:27:17 systemd-networkd[851]: wlan0: DHCP lease lost
```

After which systemd annouces the d/c and it starts some kind of reregister that also impacts my other apps that listen for the event
`Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=100 pid=851 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd " label="unconfined")`

```
Sep 11 13:27:17 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Sep 11 13:27:17 systemd-networkd[851]: wlan0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Sep 11 13:27:17 avahi-daemon[446]: Withdrawing address record for [public-ipv6] on wlan0.
Sep 11 13:27:17 avahi-daemon[446]: Withdrawing address record for [public-ipv6] on wlan0.
Sep 11 13:27:17 avahi-daemon[446]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address [public-ipv6].
Sep 11 13:27:17 avahi-daemon[446]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address [local-ipv6].
Sep 11 13:27:17 avahi-daemon[446]: Registering new address record for [local-ipv6] on wlan0.*.
Sep 11 13:27:17 dbus-daemon[448]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
```

Some info

```
description: Wireless interface
       physical id: d
       bus info: mmc@0:0001:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 54:e4:bd:7e:39:b3
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic ip=192.168.31.172 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Using rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin firmware for my wireless nic

Comment: Try disabling ipv6 if you're not using it.  Also check your wireless region setting.

Comment: @ubfan1 I am using ipv6 and I already set my region settings.
On 20.04 I didn't have any problems with the same configuration.

Comment: Seems like launchpad bug 1720580. I have an 8723bs on an older 4.4 kernel (chestersmill PPA)     6.735304] RTL871X: rtl8723bs v4.4.1_17245.20160325_BTCOEX20151223-654a
[    6.735310] RTL871X: rtl8723bs BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20151223-654a 
and a 5.10 kernel running 4.3.5.5_12290.2140916 and BTCOEX 2140507.  Both work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I know what caused this. I tried multiple changes and nothing worked so I ended up disabling wifi.

I updated my ubuntu regulary and everytime I checked if the issue was fixed and after update Package: linux-firmware Version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.6 the problem disappeared.

Fixed for:
driver=rtl8723bs driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic
version:        v4.3.5.5_12290.20140916_BTCOEX20140507-4E40